# C# DataSets batch updates

Tags: c#, database, performance, batch-file

I have a number of rows to update/insert to a SQL Server database using `TableAdapter`s.  Is there a way to batch them together, so that while it's still a list of `UPDATE` statements, at least it's only one remote call to the database?

If I was writing SQL manually, it would be a single `SqlCommand` object with a `CommandText` that looks something like this:

```
update mytable set col = val where id = 1
update mytable set col = val where id = 2
update mytable set col = val where id = 3
...
update mytable set col = val where id = 432
```

Then I would just call `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your adapter's UpdateBatchSize Property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx